# auto clear multiple input-fields

Tags: javascript, php, html

```
<?php foreach ($DATA['evidencija'] as $evidencija): ?>
                        <?php if ($evidencija->zaposleni_id == $zaposleni->zaposleni_id) { ?>
                            <?php if ($evidencija->evidencija == 'nema unosa') {?>
                                <td style="text-align:center">
                                        <input type="text" name="ime" required class="input-field" pattern="[A-z 0-9\-]+" value="8">
                                </td>
                            <?php } else { ?>
                                <td style="text-align:center; color:blue; font-size:30px"><?php  echo ($evidencija->evidencija); ?></td> 
                            <?php } ?>
                        <?php } ?>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
```

This is the portion of a code, specifically 5th line.

And I also have a button:

```
<a class="button" onclick="clearAll();">Izbrisi sva polja</a>
```

that's supposed to clear all of the input fields.

The problem is: I need all of the input fields to have '8' by default since it will be the majority of the data I will later send to the database. but I will need something to clear everything.
getElementById doesnt work, getElementByClassName doesnt work.

I need a script that will select all input fields and clear them (I assume I will have around 9300 input fields for 300 employees)

edit: function clearAll() is empty, the content of the function is what I actually need.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and post your `clearAll()` function.

Comment: It's actually Document.getElementsByClassName(). Elements not Element make sure you got that right. If still dont work please add the clearAll() function code.

Answer (score 0):

Give an ID to the Input field like below we can
**id="inputTxt"**
and clear the values of it.

`$(document).ready(function () {$("#inputTxt").value="";});`

or

```
$(".button").click(function() {
    this.value = '';
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this I hope you got your solution .

1st Method :

```js
$(".reset").click(function() {
    $(this).closest('form').find("input[type=text], textarea").val("");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="#" method="post">
 <input type="text" name="name"><br>
 <input type="text" name="email"><br>

<a href="javascript:void()" class="button reset">Izbrisi sva polja</a>
</form>
```

2nd Method :

```html
<button onclick="document.getElementById('myInput').value = ''">Clear input field</button>

<input type="text" value="Blabla" id="myInput">
```